# Edit/Update input field with React

Tags: reactjs, database, forms, fetch, edit

I'm new to react and I'm trying to edit an input field after I prefilled its value with an object value from my database, so what should I put on onChange if value is value={data.info}? because I cannot type or change the initial value. I've watched a lot of tutorials but this. and props are very confusing to me

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useAsync from '../useAsync';

export default function Details() {
  const url = 'https://..';
  const { index } = useParams();
  const { data } = useAsync(url + index);
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);



const showForm = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value={data.info} onChange={} />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}


return (
    <div className="details" >
        {data && <p key={index}>{data.info}</p>}
        <button onClick={() => setState({ showForm: true })}>Edit</button>
        {state.showForm ? showForm() : null}
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: what does the `index` do? You are not mapping over anything so? Let me create a code snippet for this.

Comment: it gives me only 1 object from a list of objects ...details/-MV_ja1hQWBi6AnVvI2W, its a details page, i can view the object, fill the input, i just cannot change the input value after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "default value" to your state. So you can move the `data` value to your `useState(false)` so `useState(data)`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [formInput, setFormInput] = useState(""); // You can add your "data" as default value

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>formInput Value {formInput}</h2>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={formInput}
        onChange={(e) => setFormInput(e.target.value)} // You need to set the state with the onchange value from the input
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Link to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-bhaskara-dy4ov?file=/src/App.js:0-486)

Comment: i tried useState(data) but the input field is empty, is it because my data object has 2 values? `{info: "fgdfgd", item: "gdfgd"}
info: "fgdfgd"
item: "gdfgd"
__proto__: Object`

Comment: if i use useState({data}) the input filled shows [object Object] and it can be changed, otherwise if i use useState({data.info}) gives me a syntax error, or if i use useState(data.info) it gives me this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of null"

Comment: why it gives you the error "Cannot read property "info""  is because the data object has not yet been populated. What you need to do is structure your use state to something like `useState({ info : '', item : ''})` that way you can do `data.info` because the key 'info' will exists.

Comment: I think i tried it, anyways im doing the edit part with plain javascript for now, thank you